# On the continuity of $xf(x)$ and $x^2f(x)$, where $f$ is the Dirichlet function

Tags: limits, continuity, special-functions

Let
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}1\qquad x\in\mathbb{Q}\\
0\qquad x\notin\mathbb{Q}
\end{cases}$$

Then how do I show that $xf(x)$ is continuous in $0$ and that $x^2f(x)$ is differentiable there as well?

When I try to visualize the Dirichlet function I get stuck thinking two parallel lines passing through $0$ and $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- To show the continuity of $x\mapsto xf(x)$ at $0$

$$|xf(x)|\le |x|\xrightarrow{x\to0}0$$

- To show the differentiability of $g:x\mapsto x^2f(x)$ at $0$

$$\left|\frac{g(x)-g(0)}{x-0}\right|=|xf(x)|\le |x|\xrightarrow{x\to0}0$$

Comment: Ok, so for the first one we have that $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0} xf(x) = 0 = f(0)$, so $f$ is continuous. I'm thinking about the second one. Thank you!

Comment: Oh for the second one we have that the derivative is continuous! So $x^2f(x)$ is said to be differentiable at $0$. Am I right? I think I get it, thanks again.

Comment: For the second we used the definition of the derivative:
$$g'(0)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{g(x)-g(0)}{x-0}$$
and since this limit exists (and equal to 0) then $g$ is differentiable at $0$ and $g'(0)=0$.